# Can't uninstall app in Windows because it's looking for the original msi file

Tags: windows, uninstall

I am trying to uninstall an application from the add/remove applications applet. However the uninstaller is looking for the original msi installer from my temp folder.

I don't have the msi file anymore and it's an older version of the app. I tried using [Microsoft's installer cleaner tool](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/9/d/e9d80355-7ab4-45b8-80e8-983a48d5e1bd/msicuu2.exe) but the uninstaller is stiill looking for the msi file.

What's a good way to completely and **cleanly** remove the app? I don't want just to delete the folder and manually delete registry entries.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [**Revo Uninstaller**](http://www.revouninstaller.com/).

> Revo Uninstaller helps you to
> uninstall software and remove unwanted
> programs installed on your computer
> even if you have problems uninstalling
> and cannot uninstall them from
> "Windows Add or Remove Programs"
> control panel applet.
>
> Revo Uninstaller is a much faster and
> more powerful alternative to "Windows
> Add or Remove Programs" applet!
>
> With its advanced and fast algorithm,
> Revo Uninstaller analyzes an
> application's data before uninstall
> and scans after you uninstall an
> application. After the program's
> regular uninstaller runs, you can
> remove additional unnecessary files,
> folders and registry keys that are
> usually left over on your computer.
> Even if you have a broken
> installation, Revo Uninstaller scans
> for an application's data on your hard
> disk drives and in the Windows
> registry and shows all found files,
> folders and registry keys so you can
> delete them.
>
> With its unique "Hunter mode", Revo
> Uninstaller offers you some simple,
> easy to use, but effective and
> powerful methods for uninstalling
> software. You can use it to manage
> your installed and/or running software
> programs.

Revo Uninstaller is free and there is also a portable version available.

Comment: Revo is great; pity it doesn't support XP x64

Answer (score 2):

As a simple solution.Reinstall the application by using installer.Then try to remove it...Good luck...

Comment: The OP said he doesn't have the installer anymore. How can he reinstall it without the installer?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to :

1. Try John's idea of using Revo Uninstaller. Only if it doesn't work, continue.
2. Delete manually anything you know belongs to the application, including Start menu entries and its installation directory.
3. Clean the registry using, for example, [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/).
4. Use Microsoft's installer cleaner tool to erase all traces of the installation.